# Can't link function time using modules in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++20, c++-modules

With the following MCVE:

```
import std.core;

int main()
{
    __int64 t = time(nullptr);

    return 0;
}
```

I get the complaint that

```
C:\...\main.cpp(9,1): error C2129: static function '__int64 time(__int64 *const )' declared but not defined
```

I'm compiling Debug/Win32. Runtime library is `/MDd`. I have `/std:c++latest` and `/experimental:module` set; command-line options are

`/JMC /experimental:module /permissive- /GS /analyze- /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /I"../../external/fmt-master/include" /ZI /Gm- /Od /Fd"Debug\vc142.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "_MBCS" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /Gd /Oy- /MDd /std:c++latest /FC /Fa"Debug\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Debug\" /Fp"Debug\modules.pch" /diagnostics:column`

Not having problems accessing `std::cout`, `std::string`, `srand`, or `sin`. What can tell Visual Studio to find the `time` function too?

Comment: The c++ standard library is not collected into modules. As such, whatever `std.core` is, it's something provided to you by Visual Studio. So you should go looking for their documentation.

Comment: Visual Studio documentation on standard library support for modules is at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/modules-cpp?view=vs-2019. "Although not specified by the C++20 standard, Microsoft enables its implementation of the C++ Standard Library to be imported as modules."

Comment: I guess that's what they mean by "experimental" and "modules are not fully implemented...".

Answer (score 0):

`std.core` provides everything else in the C++ Standard Library. However, as of Visual Studio 2019 version 16.2, Draft C++20 Standard modules are not fully implemented in the Microsoft C++ compiler. You can use the modules feature to create single-partition modules and to import the Standard Library modules provided by Microsoft. You could refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/experimental-module?view=vs-2019) for more information.

Also, You could see [Overview of modules in C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/modules-cpp?view=vs-2019) about how to create modules.